# Error when running cwl wrapper from documentation

Tags: snakemake

While running the CWL support example from snakemake documentation:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#common-workflow-language-cwl-support

I get the following error output,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/cwl-test$ snakemake -j12 "mapped/foo.sorted.bam"
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 12
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job              count    min threads    max threads
-------------  -------  -------------  -------------
samtools_sort        1              8              8
total                1              8              8

Select jobs to execute...

[Wed Oct 20 11:20:03 2021]
rule samtools_sort:
    input: mapped/foo.unsorted.bam
    output: mapped/foo.sorted.bam
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sample=foo
    threads: 8
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

/usr/bin/cwltool 1.0.20180302231433
I'm sorry, I couldn't load this CWL file, try again with --debug for more information.
The error was: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "https://github.com/common-workflow-language/workflows/blob/fb406c95/tools/samtools-sort.cwl", line 137, column 65
```

The Snakefile is almost a copy-paste of the documentation code:

```
rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        input="mapped/{sample}.unsorted.bam"
    output:
        output_name="mapped/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    params:
        threads=lambda wildcards, threads: threads,
        memory="4G"
    threads: 8
    cwl:
        "https://github.com/common-workflow-language/workflows/blob/"
        "fb406c95/tools/samtools-sort.cwl"
```

Snakemake and cwltool version in the conda envinronment are,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/cwl-test$ cwltool --version
/usr/bin/cwltool 1.0.20180302231433
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/cwl-test$ snakemake --version
6.9.1
```

How can run this example successfully?

Comment: Have you done what Snakemake asks you to, which is `try again with --debug for more information.`?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, turns out the problem was the "blob" in the cwl URL, which should be "raw" instead.

```
...
    cwl:
        "https://github.com/common-workflow-language/workflows/raw/"
        "fb406c95/tools/samtools-sort.cwl"
```

should work.

Comment: Are you sure this is the solution? is the `blob` a bug in the example documentation? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#common-workflow-language-cwl-support

Comment: My understanding is that this is a bug in the documentation. The 'blob' url leads to the download of a html file which is fails to be interpreted. The 'raw' url has no html and it executes correctly. Other examples in the documentation also use 'raw' in their urls.